# Обозначения в документации

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Возникают вопросы при чтении кода и различных документаций. Используются обозначения которые, мне не знакомы. 
Вопрос, где можно ознакомиться или как называется язык таких обозначений?
По каким правилам расставляются, следующие обозначения. Есть какая-то спецификация, что-ли...

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Например, что означает "?" после DOMString во 2ой строке

1 DOMString getAllResponseHeaders();
2 DOMString? getResponseHeader(DOMString header);

[image: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest]

или, как понимать  и как потом использовать "<" "значение" ">"  в

limit <1mb> - maximum request body size

Контекст:

> bodyParser.urlencoded([options])

Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded with the qs module. The options are:

```
limit <1mb> - maximum request body size
```

Comment: Первая часть Вашего вопроса относится к операторам. В Данном случае `?` - является тернарным оператором. Больше информации об этом Вы можете почитать тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80 Второй же вопрос относится к модулю `body-parser`. Значение используется для определения размера получаемых данных. Подробнее Вы можете прочитать в документации модуля. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Вообще, хорошо бы ссылку привести, где такое написано. В данном контексте `?` может означать необязательный параметр при описании метода. Т.е. метод `getResponseHeader()` может вернуть `undefined`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, с чего бы `?` после типа в документации становиться тернарным оператором?